# Using Cloudflare and Network Solutions, I need correct syntax for DNS configuration of SPF record

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, cloudflare, spf

I receive the following error message in outlook every time I send an email to a Gmail account. It is only Gmail accounts that are affected. I am on network solutions using microsoft exchange server. I can receive email from Gmail.

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
debbey817@gmail.com

Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.
The following organization rejected your message: gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: aesomt-co-1-6.localdomain
debbey817@gmail.com
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Remote Server returned '554 5.7.0 <gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com #5.7.26 smtp; 550-5.7.26 This mail is unauthenticated, which poses a security risk to the 550-5.7.26 sender and Gmail users, and has been blocked. The sender must 550-5.7.26 authenticate with at least one of SPF or DKIM. For this message, 550-5.7.26 DKIM checks did not pass and SPF check for [natampa.com] did not 550-5.7.26 pass with Ip: [64.78.33.163]. The sender should visit 550-5.7.26 (taking text out to google suppor) for 550 5.7.26 instructions on setting up authentication. a21-20020a05683012d500b006af8d86505dsi696609otq.65>
```

I use Cloudflare which provides security for my website natampa.com. I was told by Network Solutions to add a SPF record of:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.cloudus.oxcs.net ~all
```

to my Cloudflare account which I did and it did not work.

Unfortunately, Network Solutions is no help at all. I have been researching what to put in my SPF record and now I have this:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all
```

and it is still not working. I only have one SPF record. I have tried this:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all
```

and it did not work either.

Any guidance would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Through much perseverance, I finally found a tech at Network Solutions to help me.The correct syntax for the record is:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.serverdata.net -all
```

Comment: Cool, yeah I was about to answer that unless your email is provided by Ox, Network Solutions or Gmail none of those SPF records you tried would help. The SPF record relates to who you use to send email, completely independant of your website host. Also note, if you use any other 3rd parties to send you'll want to include them as well. For instance if your website generates email, then you'd to include that / Cloudflare themselves otherwise those emails may not reach their destination.

Comment: Thank you Keith.